# Libgdx linear velocity not working

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx

I am developing a game with libgdx for the first time.
I am using this code to set the linear velocity of my object
stepping world

```
world.step(Gdx.app.getGraphics().getDeltaTime(), 6, 2);
```

setting velocity

```
body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(new Vector2(100, 100)));
```

Body is set to be dynamic, but there is no sufficient movement for the object.

is vX = 100 too low ?

Comment: Are you setting velocity once or every time step? And, do not post delta time to world.step. Use fixed time step.

Comment: body.setLinearVelocity(new Vector2(new Vector2(100, 100)));   wot are you expecting form this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your game width and height is too large like 800x480 or something then divide it by 40 like... 20x12 ....

this is because box2d speed is limited to 2 units. and what you want is more units per time step but your screen is too big to achieve that .. so if you shorten you world then the speed problem will be solved.

Comment: my game width and height are 800 and 400. how to shorten the world?

Comment: @ShidilDinesh suppose currently your box2d body size is 80 * 40 make that size to 80/40f & 40/40f this will make the objects size small in world. make each body size divided by a constant factor. Also make camera of size 800/40f and 40/40f this will solve your problem

Comment: @ShidilDinesh every element that you use in box2d must be divided by a constant value for eg. gravity must also be divided by the same factor  that you used for shortening the world

Comment: I have an orthographic camera of size 800x480,and i use scene2d in my game . what to do? how to change size of box2d body

Comment: @ShidilDinesh when you create shape for your box2d body provide all the values by dividing it by 40 and create camera af size 20 * 12